# Count the match values and display in matrix form

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following tables with some sample data:

Table: `TblTestDB`

```
CREATE TABLE TblTestDB (id int,name varchar(100));

INSERT INTO TblTestDB VALUES(1,'Sam'),(2,'Jack'),
                            (3,'Rock'),(4,'Don'),(5,'Tam');
```

Table: `TblDB1`

```
CREATE TABLE TblDB1 (id int,name varchar(100));

INSERT INTO TblDB1 VALUES(1,'Sam'),(2,'Jack'),
                         (3,'Rock');
```

Table: `TblDB2`

```
CREATE TABLE TblDB2 (id int,name varchar(100));

INSERT INTO TblDB2 VALUES(1,'Jazz'),(2,'Dsouze'),
                         (3,'Rock'),(4,'Jack');
```

Table: `TblDB3`

```
CREATE TABLE TblDB3 (id int,name varchar(100));

INSERT INTO TblDB3 VALUES(1,'Sam'),(2,'Jazz'),
                         (3,'Rock');
```

I want to show the result in the form of:

```
TableName   Name    ID
------------------------------
TblDB1      3       3
TblDB2      2       4
TblDB3      2       3
```

Explaination about result set: I want to show count of column values which are matching between table `TblTestDB` and others(`TblDB1`,`TblDB2`,`TblDB3`).

Tried with the following query:

Query:

```
SELECT DB,MAX(Name) AS Name, MAX(ID) AS ID
FROM
(
    SELECT 'TblDB1' AS DB,COUNT(a.Name) AS Name,0 AS ID 
    FROM TblTestDB a
    INNER JOIN TblDB1 b ON a.Name = b.Name
    UNION
    SELECT 'TblDB2' AS DB,COUNT(a.Name) AS Name,0 AS ID 
    FROM TblTestDB a
    INNER JOIN TblDB2 b ON a.Name = b.Name
    UNION
    SELECT 'TblDB3' AS DB,COUNT(a.Name) AS Name,0 AS ID 
    FROM TblTestDB a
    INNER JOIN TblDB3 b ON a.Name = b.Name
    UNION
    SELECT 'TblDB1' AS DB,0 AS Name,COUNT(a.ID) AS ID 
    FROM TblTestDB a
    INNER JOIN TblDB1 b  ON a.ID = b.ID
    UNION
    SELECT 'TblDB2' AS DB,0 AS Name,COUNT(a.ID) AS ID 
    FROM TblTestDB a
    INNER JOIN TblDB2 b  ON a.ID = b.ID
    UNION
    SELECT 'TblDB3' AS DB,0 AS Name,COUNT(a.ID) AS ID 
    FROM TblTestDB a
    INNER JOIN TblDB3 b ON a.ID = b.ID
) a
GROUP BY DB
```

Issue: I may get more than 10 columns to show like matrix/pivot, the above query grows as per the columns list. 
Any better way to make it short and simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'TblDB1' AS DB
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN a.Name = b.Name THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Name
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN a.ID = b.ID THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ID 
FROM TblTestDB a
CROSS JOIN TblDB1 b
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'TblDB2' AS DB
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN a.Name = b.Name THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Name
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN a.ID = b.ID THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ID 
FROM TblTestDB a
CROSS JOIN TblDB2 b
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'TblDB3' AS DB
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN a.Name = b.Name THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Name
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN a.ID = b.ID THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ID 
FROM TblTestDB a
CROSS JOIN TblDB3 b
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple enough?

```
SELECT 
    tableName, sum(s.[Name]) as ncnt, max(s.id) as ID
FROM TblTestDB t
cross apply (
    SELECT tableName, count(name) as [name], max(id) as ID
    FROM (
        SELECT 'TblDB1' as tid, * FROM TblDB1
        union
        SELECT 'TblDB2' as tid, * FROM TblDB2
        union
        SELECT 'TblDB3' as tid, * FROM TblDB3
    ) i
    where i.name = t.name
    group by tableName
) s
group by tableName
```

Not sure what you mean by, "I may get more than 10 columns to show like matrix/pivot".
Eg, if you're going to add a Surname column, should that be matched independently, or in combination with the Name column?  (The former might get a bit complicated...)